# Laravel Not Broadcasting to Socket.IO Client

Tags: laravel, sockets, events, websocket, socket.io

I have created a laravel event:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class AssetsInfo implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $actionId;
    public $actionData;

    
    public function __construct($actionId, $actionData)
    {
        $this->actionId = $actionId;
        $this->actionData = $actionData;
    }

    
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('sahmshenas-channel');
    }

 
    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'actionId' => $this->actionId,
            'actionData' => $this->actionData,

        ];
    }
}
```

Then, I created the socket server like this:

```
'use strict';
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:8000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
        credentials: true
    }
});
require('dotenv').config();

var redisPort = process.env.REDIS_PORT;
var redisHost = process.env.REDIS_HOST;
var ioRedis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new ioRedis(redisPort, redisHost);
redis.subscribe('sahmshenas-channel');
redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    message  = JSON.parse(message);
    console.log('Notification Recieved: ' + message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

var broadcastPort = process.env.BROADCAST_PORT;
server.listen(broadcastPort, function () {
    console.log('Socket server is running.');
});
```

Here is the route which is inside Auth Middleware:

```
Route::get('/', [PageController::class, 'dashboard'])->name('dashboard');
```

Here is the controller for this route:

```
class PageController extends Controller
{
    
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $actionId = 'score_update';
        $actionData = array('team1_score' => 46);
        event(new AssetsInfo($actionId, $actionData));
        return view('pages/dashboard', [
        ]);
    }
```

The dashboard view:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Team A Score</h1>
    <div id="team1_score"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-3.0.3.min.js"> </script>
<script>
    var sock = io("{{ env('PUBLISHER_URL') }}:{{ env('BROADCAST_PORT') }}");
    sock.on('sahmshenas-channel:App\\Events\\AssetsInfo', function (data){
        //data.actionId and data.actionData hold the data that was broadcast
        //process the data, add needed functionality here
        var action = data.actionId;
        var actionData = data.actionData;
        if(action == "score_update" && actionData.team1_score) {
            $("#team1_score").html(actionData.team1_score);
        }
    });
    sock.on('error', function (reason){
        console.error('Unable to connect Socket.IO', reason);
    });
</script>
```

And finally, the ENV configuration:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=***
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=panel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION_SECOND=mysql2
DB_HOST_SECOND=localhost
DB_PORT_SECOND=3306
DB_DATABASE_SECOND=assets_daily_info
DB_USERNAME_SECOND=root
DB_PASSWORD_SECOND=


PUBLISHER_URL=http://localhost
BROADCAST_PORT=2371

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=localhost
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Socket successfully connects to node server, But nothing happens and no data returns to it.
[image]
It just creates the initial connections, and then nothing happens. No data returns to the client.
I double-checked the socket.io version both on the server and the client. They are the same. 3.0.3.
I checked everything, including channel, event, and Redis. 
But I couldn't find the answer to this problem.
What's the issue?

Comment: P.S: Nothing happens on `redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    console.log('Notification Recieved: ' + message);
});` No logs at all.

Comment: did you follow the tutorial on the doc https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#redis ?

Comment: @ml59 yes, obviously.

Comment: have you tried with BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis

Comment: @ml59 yes I have set this

Comment: @ml59 wow! sorry dude, I've made the change in ENV file and now I'm receiving object in console, here at `redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {     console.log('Notification Recieved: ' + message); });`
 But nothing happens on the frontend, it seems that the view can't get the data. do you have any idea?

Comment: @ml59 console logs the message, I mean where I run `node server.js` But no more WebSocket connections are being made on the frontend than the initial ones, so what can be the issue?

Comment: Why don't you use Laravel echo for handling all the front end stuff ? This can eliminate a lot of bugs/issues https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

Comment: Did you fix it? I am having the same